# Arity of + and - operators in Lisp Flavored Erlang

Tags: lfe

As I am just starting with LFE I've been trying out some examples from the book (SICP, LFE version) while reading the chapters. In exercise 1.4 page 76 I see the expressions `#'+/2` and `#'-/2`.

So I enter into the REPL `(funcall #'+/2 1 2)` and get (as expected) `3`. Similarly `(funcall #'+/1 1)` gives `1`. But `(funcall #'+/3 1 2 3)` gives an error. Why is this? I could of course do `(funcall #'+/2 1 (funcall #' +/2 2 3))` but I would really like to understand if and why `#'+/3` is invalid, as it seems to be.

Lastly, somewhat tangentially, if I were implementing my own function `FUNC` how would I go about implementing the ability to accept arbitrary number of arguments in this way (funcall `#'FUNC/arity ....`). If you feel this should be a separate question, please help me with the terminology since I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also just getting started with LFE, but from what I gather, [it doesn't support variadic functions](http://lfex.github.io/hyperpolyglot/). This makes me think that the math operators only accept 2 arguments. The fact that this works: `(+ 1 2 3 4 5)` makes me think there's a macro being run on that.

LFE macros apparently *can* have any number of arguments according to [this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11302125), though I haven't taken a deep dive into macros yet.

My (n00b) advice is: if you think you need a variadic function, try passing a list to your function instead of variable arguments. If you still *really* think you need a variadic function, look into making it a macro.

I suspect it's sound advice to say: avoid writing macros, unless there really isn't a better option. They're harder to analyze, debug, and consume in every language I've ever used, and while they're better in LISP than in most other languages, I think that advice still holds.

Comment: Yes, I am also starting to come to the same conclusion. I get the impression there is a primitive add function which only takes two arguments, and the + function is implemented to accept a list of arguments and process it  recursively. Probably, the base case (list with single element) of that recursion is written to return the single element itself - which is why #'+/1 works. Alternatively, there are two + functions with different arity: one takes a single element and returns it and the other takes two (and calls the former recursively). I only guess this not knowing much about Erlang either.